# how to create a fav icon shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, favicon

i wonder if there is a good way to create a shortcode that retrives a remote website FAV icon... i found this: [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702059) and tried to create a shortcode using it but failed (since i sux at shortcodes!)

A quote from the answer i linked up:

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://example.com/';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$arr = $xml->xpath('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]');
echo $arr[0]['href'];
?>
```

Any help would be apreaciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... as it sometimes goes i cant rest until i find
a way and i found a way to get the fave icon to
proeprly display using google :)

its really simple:

```
// here i get my URL from my custom post type
$directoryNoHttpUrl = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'directory_url', true );

//here i clean the url from HTTP or it wont work
$directoryNoHttpUrl = str_replace("http://", "", $directoryNoHttpUrl);

// here i get the favICON using google.. 
$imgurl = "http://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=" . $directoryNoHttpUrl;
```

.

So.. from here on its easy.
Sorry to trouble anyone entering to help
but thanks for your intention

Cheers, Sagive.